# steps to install flex plugin into flash builder

Tags: apache-flex

I just wanna install flex plugin into flash builder. Im using eclipse juno currently.I googled well.but not get succeed.How could i do tht step in process?

I want to do like below image:

[image]

Comment: I know there is a plugin for eclipse regarding FlexBuilder but I did not know there is also one for FLashBuilder.

Comment: I think you are very confused... Flash Builder is just Eclipse bundled with a Flash Plugin.  Are you sure you already have Flash Builder installed?  IF so, then you already have the Flash Plugin installed.